# How to fill a dataset from dbml

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, reporting-services, dataset

My database named "myDataBase" contains a table named "Civilities" and a table named "Languages", there is a foreign key from civilities to languages.

I've created a stored procedure named "getCivilityList" who get back information from the "Civilities" and "Languages" tables.

I work with Linq To Object, so I have a DataContext which has a method name "getCivilityList()" corresponding to my stored procedure.

I use reporting services to generate a Civilities list. In my template (.RDLC) I have a tablix linked to my "getCivilityList" stored procedure.

my RDLC template wait for a DataSet as ReportDataSource, so I would fill a DataSet with de result of my myDataContext.getCivilityList()

Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks !

Olivier

Answer (score 2):

LINq-to-SQL (dbml) is expressly *not* about `DataSet`sl it is about object orientation. If you want to fill a `DataSet`, you may want to look to regular ADO.NET - maybe via a data-adapter, maybe just by `ExecuteReader`.